# Combobox - setting datasource clears Items

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

I have a routine that populates a combobox from a database; the first time the combo is populated, it all works perfectly, but if I try to do it again, the combobox is completely blank. I narrowed it down to this line:

```
        cboThis.DataSource = cboThis.Items;
```

This seems to clear the Items collection for the combobox...but only if the combo was already populated.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

There *IS* an event handler for one of the combo's SelectedIndexChanged event, but this doesn't seem to get called by anything but the first and last lines of code.

Here's the complete routine:

```
public void ComboFromDB(ComboBox cboThis, string strTable, string strField)
    {
        cboThis.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cboThis.DataSource = null;
        cboThis.Items.Clear();
        string strQuery = @"SELECT ID, " + strField + " FROM " + strTable;
        using (SqlConnection sqcConnection = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
        {
            sqcConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand sqcCommand = new SqlCommand(strQuery, sqcConnection);
            SqlDataReader dr = sqcCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                cboThis.Items.Add(new ComboItem((int)dr[0], dr[1].ToString())); //this all works fine
            }
        }
        cboThis.DataSource = cboThis.Items; //This line clears cboThis.Items...
        cboThis.ValueMember = "ID";
        cboThis.DisplayMember = "Display";
        cboThis.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: This line seems a bit incestuous and perhaps recursive:  cboThis.DataSource = cboThis.Items;  What are you trying to accomplish by doing that?  It looks like you are NOT databinding but filling the combobox manually.

Comment: I believe you need to set a datasource to be able to use the SelectedValue property, hence the datasource.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? I'm still struggling with this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end I binned using Items and just shoved it through a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

try to create a structure like this

```
struct tmpItems
{
    //member variables
    private Int32 _ID;
    private String _Display;

    //properties
    public Int32 ID
    {
        get {return _ID;}
    }

    public String Display
    {
        get {return _Display;}
    }

    public tmpItems(Int32 pID , String pDisplay)
    {
        _ID = pID;
        _Display = pDisplay;
    } 
}
```

now assign

```
ArrayList dataItems = new ArrayList();
dataItems.Add(new tmpItems((int)dr[0], dr[1].ToString()));
```

then finally set

```
cbothis.DataSource = dataItems;
cboThis.ValueMember = "ID";
cboThis.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

Ensure that ComboBox SelectedIndexChange event handles the Initialization of data..
because while setting datasource , the items will be added one by one.. each time generating SelectedIndexChangeEvent .. but will find difficult in accessing  SelectedValue property at this stage